# How do I print a statement then delete item in F#

Tags: f#

I have this program that I have created in F#.  I need to accept a sentence and then return the sentence stating their each words/character's part of speech and the word/character.  How do I read something in, match with the mapStrToken and print out the word/character and the part of speech?

I have this code here:

```
type tokens = Art of string | Noun of string | Adj of string 
                | Adv of string |
                | Verb of string | Comma of string | Conj of string
                |Prep of string | EOS of string | NONE;;
let mapStrToken str = 
    match str with
        | "dog" -> Noun str | "cat" -> Noun str | "mouse" -> Noun str | "tree" -> Noun str | "cheese" -> Noun str
        | "a" -> Art str | "the" -> Art str
        | "likes" -> Verb str | "hates" -> Verb str | "eats" -> Verb str | "chases" -> Verb str
        | "," -> Comma str
        | "." -> EOS str | "!" -> EOS str
        | "fast" -> Adj str | "slow" -> Adj str | "furry" -> Adj str | "yellow" -> Adj str
        | "quickly" -> Adv str | "slowly" -> Adv str | "quietly" -> Adv str
        | "and" -> Conj str | "or" -> Conj str
        | "of" -> Prep str | "around" -> Prep str
        | _ -> NONE
```

Comment: It is not clear what your goal is and what problems you encountered. Try to rephrase your question to make it clearer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I suspect your use case is something like `"a fast , yellow dog".split(' ') |> Array.map mapStrToken |> processTokenArray`, but I don't know what your output for processTokenArray would be.

Comment: A word of advice since I suspect that you're asking for help with a homework problem: most professors will be absolutely fine with you asking for help, *as long as you disclose it*. Put a comment in your code that mentions "I asked for help at http://stackoverflow.com/q/43857644, and this function came from the person who helped me" (or similar wording) and you should be fine. Depending on your professor's policies, if you don't disclose it he/she might view that as cheating. If this isn't homework, of course, disregard this comment.

Comment: Also, this question has nothing to do with Visual Studio itself, so I'm going to remove those tags from the question. It's better to tag a question with tags that are relevant to the question itself. Here, you may be using VS to write your program, but you would have the same question if you were using a different IDE, so the only relevant tag is `f#`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but try this.

```
let tokenArray = "a fast , yellow dog".Split(' ') |> Array.map mapStrToken 
let doSomethingWithTokens = function
    | [Art; Adj; Comma; Adj; Noun] -> Some("article adjective comma adjective noune")
    | _ -> None
tokenArray |> doSomethingWithtokens
```